# Seeking a Function Object with implicit return — similar to Arrow Function

Tags: javascript

Arrow functions provide the convenience of implicit return. I am trying to achieve something similar via the Function Object but couldn't find anything. Essentially I need to evaluate an expression using the Function Object but get the value of the expression assuming the semantics of

```
`() => ${expression}`
```

result in implicit return. The function object itself is created as

```
new Function(expression)
```

The expression in this for example can be "new Date()". Workaround is to have the expression specified as "return new Date()" but it's less convenient for the person providing the expression.

Comment: `new Function('return ' + expression)`?

Comment: The expression can be a block of statements in which case it doesn't meet the implicit return semantics. I can't blindly prefix it with 'return '.

Comment: Can you add some examples of what values `expression` can have?

Comment: It can be any valid javascript code. The expectation is that if it is complex code, user has to explicitly use the return statement but if it's a single expression, they wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

So the idea is to force a return value on an expression that doesn't have one.

Here's the beginning of a possible solution that extends `Function` to another class named `FWithReturn`

`FWithReturn` simply prepends the `return` when none exists, then passes along to the Function constructor.

This example is for a simple expression with or without a `return`, or a complex expression with a `return`.

Note: This method fails to return a value, for an IIFE like `(function(){ return 42; })()`.

```js
class FWithReturn extends Function {
  constructor(...args) {
    let fnBody = args[args.length - 1].replace(/\s/g, '');
    
    // detect IIFE (begins with '(', includes ')()')
    let isIIFE = Boolean(fnBody.match(/^\(/) &&
        fnBody.match(/\)\(\)/));
    
    if (isIIFE || !fnBody.includes("return")) {
      args[args.length - 1] = "return " +  args[args.length - 1];
    }
    super(...args);
  }
}

// simple expression
const a = new FWithReturn("a", "b", "a + b");
addRes('FWithReturn("a", "b", "a + b")', a, a(10, 5));

// simple expression with return
const b = new FWithReturn("a", "b", "return a + b");
addRes('FWithReturn("a", "b", "return a + b")', b, b(100, 50));

// compound expression with return
const c =
  new FWithReturn("let d = new Date(); return d.toLocaleTimeString();");
addRes(
  'FWithReturn("let d = new Date(); return d.toLocaleTimeString();"', c, c());

// IIFE that returns a value
const d = new FWithReturn("(function(){ return 42; })();");
addRes('FWithReturn("(function(){ return 42; })();")', d, d());
```

```html
<pre id="result">Results:

</pre>
<script>
  const result = document.getElementById('result');

  const addRes = function(fn, newFn, val) {
    result.innerHTML +=  fn + '\n' + newFn + '\nReturns: ' +
      val + '\n\n';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This will fail in a general case where the return expression is itself a function with its own return. It seems like it requires a full fledged parsing to be sure but I was hoping there is a built-in way to do it.

Comment: @Siva Can you provide an example of a function with return case that fails? I'm having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: See the result for "e" I have added to your test cases.